# Getting the array sorted in relation to a value Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Let's say I have an array arr of doubles:

```
arr = 120,121,118,119,117,123,120
```

And a value x

```
x = 120
```

I want to get this value

```
newarr = 120,120,119,121,118,117,123
```

Which is a new array, the same size of arr, but the values are sorted in relation to the value x, having the closest value first (doesn't matter if it's ascending or descending).

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach -

```
[~,idx] = sort(abs(x-arr))
out = arr(idx)
```

Output -

```
out =
   120   120   121   119   118   117   123
```

Since, `191` & `121` are equidistant from `x = 120`, the output values appear to be different than the ones listed in the expected output of the problem. In this  approach, when two such equidistant values appear in `arr`, the ones appearing at the start are put at the start in the output array too, thus the order of elements is `maintained` or it's `stable` in the output array. As, an example to demonstrate this "stability", here's a sample run with modified `arr`  and keeping `x` the same at `120`  -

```
>> arr
arr =
   120   121   118   119   117   123   121   119
>> out
out =
   120   121   119   121   119   118   117   123
```

Note: If you would like to have an ascending order for the equidistant elements, you can first sort `arr` and then use this approach.